# Error: Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \mathplus

Tags: bibliographies, errors, biber

i am new to LaTeX and i have a problem.

This is my tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\bibliography{ref/literatur}

\begin{document}    
    
    Test \autocite{MSPP}
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

This is my bib file:

```
@Book{MSPP,
  title     = {Multilayered Security and Privacy Protection in Car-to-X Networks},
  publisher = {Springer Science $\mathplus$ Business Media},
  year      = {2013},
  author    = {Hagen Stübing},
  doi       = {10.1007/978-3-658-02531-1},
  url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-658-02531-1},
}
```

I got this error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \mathplus
```

But I never use mathplus.. ?!
When I % the \printbibliography, there isn't any error, but also no Reference List :-D

Any ideas what to do?!

Thanks in advance

## fromGermany

Comment: You have `publisher = {Springer Science $\mathplus$ Business Media},`. Replacing `$\mathplus$` by `+` should be enough.

Comment: This ist awesome!! thanks a lot, i was about 2 hours to find out this sh*t :-D Thanks! I could not find the error even though it is obvious.

Comment: @KolaB., do you mind to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Zarko Done. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `publisher = {Springer Science $\mathplus$ Business Media},`. Replacing `$\mathplus$` by `+` should be enough.